# multi modules project management in java maven

Tags: java, git, spring-boot, maven, project-management

Let’s say in a multi-module project, each module is created by different teams, but each module is important for the project to work.
Each team should have its own module code, while other modules should appear in jar form.
Even when working through this git, they don’t have to see modifications in module codes that don’t belong to them.
But to test the project on the whole team, all the modules need to be used together.
I can do a multi-module project through maven, but when I put it on git, do I have to put each module in a separate repository?
how to they will find out what other module is in the new version in the version update of the modules?

Comment: If you are working on a team then all code should be visible to all of the team members and that could make a multi module build which I suppose will be released at the same time. If you don't like to get seen code by others (which is violation of a team) you should make separate git repos of it but don't misuse a multi module build with sub trees etc of it. And prevent team members to see code changes does not make sense...sounds like a wrong working environment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide:

Will these modules always be built and tested together?

If yes: Put them into *one* git repository and use a multi-module structure. Everyone will checkout everything, but make changes only for their module.

If no: Separate the project in two or more multi-module projects in separate git repositories.